# CoreOS not able to login with provided username and password in cloud-config file?

Tags: docker, containers, virtualbox, coreos, spring-cloud-config

So I'm running CoreOS on VirtualBox. I booted up the VM and used

```
sudo openssl passwd -1 > cloud-config-file
```

And it prompted me for a password, which I entered. Then my cloud config file looks like this:

```
#cloud-config

users:

- name: test

- passwd: 'provided password hash'

  groups:

  - sudo

  - docker
```

And then I try and install the image with

```
sudo coreos-install -d /dev/sda -C stable -c cloud-config-file
```

And it successfully installs, I shut down the VM, unmount the disk, and reboot the VM and it prompts me for a login and password. I use the provided credentials in the cloud config file and it keeps telling me "login incorrect". Why is this happening? It seems that I've done all the steps correctly.